# Why doesn't vimtutor claim match reality?

Tags: vim

Here's a quote from vimtutor:

```
                        Lesson 2.1: DELETION COMMANDS

                       ** Type  dw  to delete a word. **

  1. Press  <ESC>  to make sure you are in Normal mode.

  2. Move the cursor to the line below marked --->.

  3. Move the cursor to the beginning of a word that needs to be deleted.

  4. Type   dw   to make the word disappear.

  NOTE: The letter  d  will appear on the last line of the screen as you type
        it.  Vim is waiting for you to type  w .  If you see another character
        than  d  you typed something wrong; press  <ESC>  and start over.
```

But that NOTE doesn't reflect my experience - the letter 'd' simply doesn't appear (and neither does any other letter). Why is there this inconsistency between vimtutor and my experience?

(vim version 7.4, vimtutor version 1.7)

Comment: Because you are special.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably an oversight. That feature is governed by the `showcmd` option which appears to be false while the author of the `vimtutor` expects it to be true.

You should submit this issue on [the vim mailing list](http://www.vim.org/maillist.php#vim).